# How to reduce part of a dataframe colunm value based on another column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this.

I am trying to remove the string which presents in substring column.

```
Main                     substring
Sri playnig well cricket cricket
sri went out             NaN
Ram is in                NaN
Ram went to UK,US        UK,US
```

My expected outupt is,

```
Main                     substring
Sri playnig well         cricket
sri went out             NaN
Ram is in                NaN
Ram went to              UK,US
```

I tried `df["Main"].str.reduce(df["substring"])` but not working, pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using `pd.DataFrame.apply`. Note that `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`, we can use this trick in our function to determine when to apply removal logic.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Main': ['Sri playnig well cricket', 'sri went out',
                            'Ram is in' ,'Ram went to UK,US'],
                   'substring': ['cricket', np.nan, np.nan, 'UK,US']})

def remover(row):
    sub = row['substring']
    if sub != sub:
        return row['Main']
    else:
        lst = row['Main'].split()
        return ' '.join([i for i in lst if i!=sub])

df['Main'] = df.apply(remover, axis=1)

print(df)

               Main substring
0  Sri playnig well   cricket
1      sri went out       NaN
2         Ram is in       NaN
3       Ram went to     UK,US
```

Comment: can you check this one https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31538/how-to-perform-mean-median-operation-on-a-factorial

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner should do it:

```
df.loc[df['substring'].notnull(), 'Main'] = df.loc[df['substring'].notnull()].apply(lambda x: x['Main'].replace(x['substring'], ''), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but this takes more time than jpp's solution

Comment: A trivial improvement is to define `mask = df['substring'].notnull()` in a separate line. But then it would be not be a one-liner.